# What is the purpose of the ... before array of the objects

Tags: angular, typescript, angular7

I am currently learning Angular and have found example of the code that is a bit mysterious for me.

I have a function that return `Observable<Product[]>` array of objects:

```
  connect(): Observable<Product[]> {

    const dataMutations = [
      this.productsSubject,
      this.paginator.page,
      this.sort.sortChange
    ];

    return merge(...dataMutations).pipe(map((products) => {
      this.paginator.length = products.length;
      return this.getPagedData(this.getSortedData([...products]));
    }));
  }
```

In this code block, there is the function `getSortedData` that takes `[...products]` what is purpose of the `...` before the array of products?

Code sample of the `getSortedData`:

```
private getSortedData(data: Product[]) {
    if (!this.sort.active || this.sort.direction === '') {
      return data;
    }

    return data.sort((a, b) => {
      const isAsc = this.sort.direction === 'asc';
      switch (this.sort.active) {
        case 'title': return compare(a.title, b.title, isAsc);
        default: return 0;
      }
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [MDN web docs Spread Syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax):

> Spread syntax allows an iterable such as an array expression or string
>   to be expanded in places where zero or more arguments (for function
>   calls) or elements (for array literals) are expected, or an object
>   expression to be expanded in places where zero or more key-value pairs
>   (for object literals) are expected.

From [MDN web docs Rest parameters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/rest_parameters):

> The rest parameter syntax allows us to represent an indefinite number
>   of arguments as an array.

Answer (score 3):

It's `Spread syntax`

More info: https://code4developers.com/spread-syntax-in-javascript/

Answer (score 2):

It represents the `es6 spread operator`.
In your case, it allows you to pass a **shallow** copy of your `products` array.